# HTML within markdown files doesn't get rendered

Tags: azure-devops

I have a table that I need to include in a markdown document in our TFS 2017 on-prem repository. The table needs to include multiple values separated by a line break within one of the columns. I can write it and see the expected results using HTML tags in Visual Studio Code however, TFS 2017 doesn't render it correctly.

```
Top of the **markdown** file

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Example</th>
        <th>Required</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>app-name</td>
        <td>The name of the application that the resource was provisioned for.</td>
        <td>The app name is a simplified version of the project-name tag below, if the resource was created for a project. Otherwise, use the product name.</td>
        <td>foo-bar<br/>product-evaluation</td>
        <td>If associated to an app, yes.</td>
    </tr>
</table>

Bottom of the *markdown* file.
```

Taking the above markdown file example, Visual Studio renders it like this:

[image: VS Code]

Once I've pushed it to TFS 2017 however, the HTML isn't rendered at all. The markdown parts are still rendered correctly though.

[image: TFS 2017]

Is this expected behavior, and is there anything on the roadmap to support HTML within markdown files? The markdown specifications support this. If HTML isn't supported, what can I do to use line-breaks in a standard MD table column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's the expected behavior.

For now, it's not supported for TFS on-premise. However in VSTS (TFS on line) it can be rendered in preview, but still cannot be rendered in **Dashboard** (Add to dashboard).

We don’t have a public timeline for this feature to support right now. However VSTS alread support the preview, So maybe will full support soon. You can track the feature timeline in here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive-vso, that’s the first place update.

In your scenario you can use Markdown to render the table instead of html:

You can create tables by assembling a list of words and dividing them with hyphens `-` (for the first row), and then separating each column with a pipe `|`:

```
| Key | Description | Value |  Example |Required |
|-----------|:-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|-----------:|
| app-name  | The name of the application that the resource was provisioned for. |The app name is a simplified version of the project-name tag below, if the resource was created for a project. Otherwise, use the product name. | foo-bar product-evaluation | If associated to an app, yes.|
```

See [Syntax guidance for Markdown files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/collaborate/markdown-guidance#tables) for details.

Besides, [Wiki](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs2018-relnotes#wiki) feature introduced in TFS 2018, it supports for HTML tags in markdown. You can upgrade to TFS 2018 if that's an option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was originally using markdown but couldn't use line breaks in the individual columns. Because of that, I moved to html so I could use `br/>` within columns. I ended up just changing the html back into markdown and not using line-breaks in the columns for the time being.